# Initializing a field to an object and using two int's - JAVA

Tags: java, object, initialization

Just a quick and easy question, I'm doing a small project/assignment for a course and I wonder if any of you could kindly point out where I'm going wrong here. The question states:

***Write a new class called GeometricShape. Add a field of type Point called center to represent the geometric center of the shape.***

***Add a constructor to the GeometricShape class that takes in two int’s, which are used to initialize the center variable. Display the message “Constructing a GeometricShape”. Within the constructor, initialize the field center to a new Point object, using the two int’s that were passed in to the constructor.***

Here is the code that I have managed to come up with so far (assume Point is Testing):

```
    public class Testing{
        public int x;
        public int y;


        Testing(int i, int k){
            i = x;
            k = y;
            System.out.println("Constructing a Point");
        }

    class GeometricShape{
        Testing center;

            GeometricShape(int z, int v){

            System.out.println("Constructing a GeometricShape");
            center c = new Testing(z, v);
        }
    }

 }
```

When I attempt the last line of code to get the error: 'Unknown class: 'center''.

So I'm having trouble initializing the field center to a new Testing(Point) object.

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: center = new Testing(z, v); - is this what you are trying to do? center is a name of a variable, not a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be using

```
center = new Testing(z, v);
```

Since `center` is the name for the `Testing` instance.

Also, in your `Testing(int, int)` constructor, you have the assignments for `x` and `y` backwards.

Comment: This looks like it's fixed the issue, Thanks. I need to brush up on Java, I've really been slacking!

Comment: Don't forget to change i = x;
            k = y;
to x = i; y = k;